# Jpa: Storing collection of Value objects composed by Entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

```
@Entity
class Question{
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String questionText;

    @OneToMany
    Set<AnswerOption> answerOptions;
}

class AnswerOption{
    private String option;

    @ManyToOne
    private Question question;
}

table-columns:
Question: id, text 
AnswerOption: question_id, option

example:
Question: Which county are you from?
Possible answers: Kent, Essex, Middlesex, Others


Intended api usage:
Question q = new Question("Which county are you from?");
q.addAnswerOption(new AnswerOption("Kent"))
q.addAnswerOption(new AnswerOption("Essex"))
q.addAnswerOption(new AnswerOption("Middlesex"))
q.addAnswerOption(new AnswerOption("Others"))
questionDao.save(q);
```

I do not need an identifier for AnswerOption as I consider AnswerOption to be a Value object. Can someone recommed how to persist this model using JPA as I am unsure of the annotations to use for AnswerOption class?

Thanks.

Comment: If you already have the OO model, you have the persistence of it (the purpose of JPA is automating that work). Now, which is the **real question**?

Comment: as you can see I have not marked AnswerOption class with relevant JPA annotations as I am not sure how to store value objects with JPA.

Answer (score 3):

I would say, make your `AnswerOption` class also as entity.

```
@Entity
class AnswerOption{
   private String option;

   @ManyToOne
   private Question question;
 }
```

Change `oneToMany` mapping in `Question` class to use `CASCADE` option as below:

```
 @Entity
 class Question{

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String questionText;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="question")
    Set<AnswerOption> answerOptions;
 }
```

Once done, save your question object as below:

```
 //get your hibernate session
 Session session = ....
 Question q = new Question("Which county are you from?");
 q.addAnswerOption(new AnswerOption("Kent"))
 q.addAnswerOption(new AnswerOption("Essex"))
 q.addAnswerOption(new AnswerOption("Middlesex"))
 q.addAnswerOption(new AnswerOption("Others"))

 //use session to save the Question with AnswerOptionss
 session.save(q);
```

Make sure your `addAnswerOption` method in `Question` as below:

```
 public void addAnswerOption(AnswerOption answerOption){
     //setting the question as parent in answerOption
     answerOption.setQuestion(this).
     this.answerOptions.add(answerOption);
 }
```

Comment: i am sure that your solution would work. but i do not think AnswerOption deserves to be an entity. it is also bound to the lifecycle of the Question. thanks for replying.

Comment: I think, `AnswerOption` is also an table with `question_id` and `option` columns. Why you think it should not be an Entity? If you notice, in the handling example, you are dealing with only `Question` i.e. `session.save(question)` and `AnswerOption` is internally taken care. Same way, you can perform `update`, `delete`, `retreive` using `question` only.

Comment: It is simple scenario of `parent-child` where `Question` is the parent table and `AnswerOption` is the the child table. It is understood, child can't exist without parent. This can also be enforced by defining `foreign-key` on `question_id` in `AnswerOtption` table with `id` column in `Question` table.

Comment: the parent child relationship exists. but the child is a value object that needs **no identity** (http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/02/13/ddd-entities-and-value-objects.aspx). if I were not using hibernate to save this model, I could easily persist the AnswerOption without a id column.

Comment: That is fine, but how does that affect you? If you map `AnswerOtption` as child entity, you can do both i.e. manage `AnswerOtption` alone or manage `AnswerOtption` along with `Question` assuming, `id` is nullable in `AnswerOtption`.